# How to get the Antergos GNOME configuration?

Tags: gnome, configuration, gnome3, antergos

I recently installed Antergos, but I had to install the Base version and then Gnome manually afterwards, because their installer is still a mess. The problem is: Now I have the boring old default Gnome configuration and not the Antergos customized Look And Feel.

I tried to find out something about their configuration, but now I know nothing more than the theme used. I tried to unsquashfs the image of the installer which has the same configuration, but the home folder there doesn't have the typical folder where I normally look for settings.

So, how do I get the configuration?

Comment: Boot from the livecd, check which icons and themes are used via tweak-tool and replicate that on your install.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I did it by launching Antergos in a VM and copying the folders out of it. But this was unnecessary, because all themes come in the Antergos repository:

```
sudo pacman -S numix-frost-themes numix-icon-theme-square numix-gtk-theme
```

For the full choice, see

```
pacman -Ss numix
```